# What kinds of long - term cognition/motivation tracking tools are there?

Tags: performance, motivation

I'm aware that there are dozens of personal "activity trackers"/ pedometers like fitbit that are aimed for mass consumer and can log activity over extended periods of time. **Are there equivalent devices or programs that automatically keep track of the users cognitive performance or motivation over extended periods of time?**

Comment: Believe it or not, I had actually build the first version of this tool and had it on the web for almost a year. It did not seem to catch on or I did not know how to market it. Anyway, it had basic functions for recording and graphing things like well being, awareness, energy level, happiness, etc - with fancy MS chart controls, gauges and Facebook sharing, I still have the code on my PC. wrote it with asp.net in C# and the Big3.

Comment: I've learned that the field is called "quantified self", and your email outbox (messages you have sent) might be a reasonably automatic indicator of your activity and motivation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic it's a Productivity question.